# Does a WriteStream have to be closed?

Tags: node.js

I used `var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('...')` to open a WriteStream, but there is no `writeStream.close()` function. How is this handled in node?

Comment: fileClose()? streamClose()? http://anwajler.com/node.html This looked good as well: `fs.close(fd, function(err){
            console.log('File closed');
            console.log(buffer.toString());
        });`

Comment: There are lots of reasons this can come up (e.g. multiple points of program termination, tedious to share a global var for the stream, want something good enough for a 30s debugging diagnostic...). Empirically, `Fs.createWriteStream` seems to emit the same output w or w/o the `close` but I'm still curious about the answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Call `stream.end()`

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_end

Comment: This answer does not explain "WHY", as for what OP asked for. It only provides link. Downvote

Answer (score 4):

Stream Has to be close after you done your file's writing work.
use

```
stream.end()
```

1. You can't use **stream.write('xxx')**  after **stream.end()**.
2. While you don't have end/close the writeable stream, you/other can write into file anytime, and NodeJS will keep writable stream's reference in RAM.